# Contains en Uri - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, webview-android

Para detectar si un string contiene una palabra especifica uso lo siguiente.

```
url = "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
if (url.contains("questions")){
.....
}
```

funciona perfecto.
Sin embargo ahora necesito usarlo desde shouldInterceptRequest y este usa URI.

```
override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): WebResourceResponse? {
                return if (request!!.url == Uri.parse("https://resource.com")) 
                .....
```

Uso lo anterior para detectar si la url URI es igual, funciona también.
Pero como dije antes necesito comprobar si contiene un palabra en especifico, pero esta vez con URI.

```
request!!.url.containst  //no funciona
```

Cual seria el homologo de contains para URI.

Answer (score 1):

Debes decidir que parte de la uri quieres evaluar y luego llamar `contains` sobre ese segmento. Por ejemplo esta uri `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin?sort=Newest` podemos separarla en:

- `scheme`: "https"
- `host`: "es.stackoverflow.com"
- `path`: "/questions/tagged/kotlin"
- `query`: "sort=Newest"

Otra propiedad útil de la clase Uri es `lastPathSegment` que en este ejemplo sería "kotlin". Volviendo a tu caso esta es la forma null-safe de escribirlo:

```
if (request?.url?.host?.contains("resource.com") == true)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`request!!.url` es una `Uri`, puedes convertirla a String](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/Uri#toString()) y de esta forma usar la función `contains()`, de esta forma puedes encontrar la url que carga dentro de `shouldInterceptRequest()` y realizar la validación :

```
if (request!!.url.toString().contains("https://resource.com"))){
 ...
 ...
}
```

---

Ejemplo:

```
  override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): WebResourceResponse? {
      if (request!!.url.toString().contains("https://resource.com")){
        //Carga url   
      }else{
        //No carga url
      }
      return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
  }
```